# VS 2015 Method Overload Resolution Behavior

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2015, overloading

I'm having a hard time understanding why the correct overload isn't being selected in this simple example. Looking in the [C# 5 spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) under 7.5.3.2 Better function member, it seems that it should be able to select the non-generic overload, but the `object` parameter seems to play into the decision somehow that I'm not understanding. The problem I'm having is that I cannot call the non-generic version of `Foo(object)` without casting the argument to `object`. From the error it looks like it isn't supported and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the reason.

```
public class A
{
    public string Type { get { return "non-generic"; } }
}

public class A<T>
{
    public string Type { get { return "generic"; } }
}

class Program
{
    // (In reality only one of the variants below can be uncommented.)
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // This works fine and calls the generic overload as expected
        A<string> x = Foo<string>("foobar");

        // This results in a compile time error
        // CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'A<string>' to 'A'
        A x = Foo("foobar");

        // This works, but ends up calling the generic overload
        var x = Foo("foobar");

        // This works fine and calls the non-generic overload as expected
        object a = "foobar";
        var x = Foo(a);

        // This works fine and calls the non-generic overload as expected
        A x = Foo((object)"foobar");

        // By using dynamic we're able to get rid of the compile-time error, but get a
        // runtime exception.
        // RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'A<string>' to 'A'
        A x = Foo((dynamic)"foobar");

        Console.WriteLine(x.Type);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static A Foo(object x)
    {
        return new A();
    }

    private static A<T> Foo<T>(T x)
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the compile time error is because Foo("foobar") is creating an A<string> (generic) for you, which you then try to put into a variable of type A (non-generic). As far as the compiler is concerned they are 2 completely different types. If you were to use: var x = Foo("foobar"); it would probably compile

Comment: You're right that var x = Foo("foobar"); compiles and runs. It also calls the generic overload. Is there no way to call the non-generic overload without explicitly casting to object or passing object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
A x = Foo("foobar");
```

C# selects the generic method, since it is more specific than the non-generic one and requires no conversion. In fact, the C# compiler creates a copy of the Foo method and replaces the generic type parameter `T` by the concrete type `string`. The overload resolution is performed at compile time. At run time a method with a string parameter will be called. No generic overhead is created at run time.

Note that only the expression on the right side of the assignment is taken into account for the resolution. More specifically, C# looks at the method signature, i.e. the method parameters. The return type of a method does *not* belong to its signature.

The generic method returns an `A<T>`, but since `A<T>` does not derive from `A`, the result of type `A<T>` of the method `Foo<T>()` cannot be assigned to `x`, which is of type `A`. The same is true for the example with dynamic: there is no valid conversion from `A<T>` to `A`. Since overload resolution is done at compile time, dynamics cannot solve your problem. Dynamics are doing their "job" (i.e. binding) at runtime.

Again, it's not the result that you expect from a method that determines which overload is used, but the (static) arguments passed to this method.

---

Another example that helps to clarify the facts:

```
var x = Foo(5);
var y = Foo("hello");
```

At compile time C# creates two copies of the Foo method! One with `int` and one with `string` in place of the generic type parameter `T`. At runtime no conversion occurs; not even a boxing (unlike Java which would wrap the `int` into an object).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that it's the arguments that determine the overload that gets selected. The part that I'm hung up on is section 7.5.3.2 from the spec and how it decides which method to select. I suspect it's my not understanding the second paragraph which talks about the argument conversions. string to object must not be a better conversion that string to generic - like you point out.

Comment: There is no conversion from string to generic. In the generic case strings are used as strings and there is no conversion involved, because `A<T> Foo<T>(T x)` is then compiled to `A<string> Foo(string x)`. I.e. in the call `Foo("hello")` a string value is passed to a string parameter. In the non-generic variant a string value is passed to an `object` parameter.

Comment: Set a breakpoint into `Foo<T>` and you will see that `T` has been replaced by `string` when you hover over `x`.